# What methods exist to detect airframe icing, and how do they work?

Tags: airframe, icing

What are the primary methods used to detect ice on an airframe, and how do they work on at least a high level?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to sense ice on an airframe. The [DOT has a document](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a266273.pdf) here that outlines the various types of sensors.

First and foremost planes have ice lights that project onto the wings so they can be visually inspected.

There are [completely optical sensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_detector) that use a variety of methods to detect ice.

There are also some electro mechanical devices, here are a few examples, the rest are outlined in the [DOT document](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a266273.pdf).

> **Penny and Giles**
>
> The Penny and Giles system uses a probe type sensor that measures ice
>   buildup in terms of Liquid Water Content (LWC). This system was
>   designed specifically for use on helicopters and is available for all
>   turbine-powered helicopters.
>
> **Rosemount**
>
> The sensing probe is driven magnetostrictively to vibrate at its
>   resonant frequency of 40,000 Hz. As the ice detector enters an icing
>   environment, ice collects on the sensing probe. The added mass of the
>   accreted ice causes the frequency of the sensing probe to decrease in
>   accordance with the laws of classical mechanics.
>
> **Sunstrand**
>
> The Sunstrand system uses a mounted probe with a sensing surface
>   facing the airstream. Beta particles are released from a Strontium 90
>   Radiation Source and are collimated by a specially shaped window in
>   the probe housing. These particles pass across the sensing surface to
>   a Geiger-Muller tube. High voltage is applied to the Geiger-Muller
>   tube to enable it to detect the radiation emitted by the Strontium 90
>   source. Ice accretion on the probe decreases the beta particles
>   detected by the tube. When the particle count drops below a pre-set
>   level, a pulse rate discriminating amplifier energizes an icing signal
>   visible to the flight crew. At this time a heater inside the probe is
>   activated, the ice is removed from the probe, and the probe is ready
>   to begin another icing cycle.

Some of these will work in a static situation while others may require the passage from a non icing environment to an icing situation.